# Override Method Group On-The-Fly

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have a base class that implements an interface:

```
internal interface ITest
{
    virtual void GetData();
}

internal class Test : ITest
{
    public void GetData()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test - Hello World!");
    }
}
```

It is used by inheriting the **Test** class and overriding the **GetData()** method:

```
internal class SubTest : Test
{
    public override void GetData()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SubTest - Hello World!");
    }
}
```

I have hundreds of stored procedures that each need to be called 1 time. Creating a new class like **SubTest** for each stored procedure that inherits from **Test** seems like overkill.

Is there a way to write a Lambda Expression, Anonymous Method, or Action that will let me override the empty default method?

What I'm thinking is something along these lines:

```
var t = new Test();
t.GetData = delegate()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Anonymous - Hello World!");
};
```

Is there any way to write an override for a method *on-the-fly* like that?

### Solved!

I used Evk's technique to apply what Gusman showed:

```
internal interface ITest
{
    virtual void GetData();
}

internal class Test : ITest
{
    public void GetData()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Call from Test");
    }
}

internal class SubTest : Test
{
    private readonly Action _localTest;
    public SubTest(Action localTest)
    {
        _localTest = localTest;
    }
    public override void GetData()
    {
        base.GetData();
        _localTest();
    }
}
```

Here is how I implemented it:

```
class ClassTester
{
    public void Run()
    {
        var t = new Test(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Anonymous Override of Test");
            }
        );
        t.GetData();
    }
}
```

Comment: Given that `Test` doesn't have an implementation it shouldn't even be a class.  Just have the classes that would derived from it implement the interface.

Comment: @Servy - For the sake of this example, I put something simple up there. It is not our full company database class. Should I add the details?

Comment: @Servy, I edited the question to show where each method is being called from.

Comment: You could make a class whose `GetData` method simply executes a delegate, set via public property (or passed in the ctor).

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot pass the stored procedure name as a parameter to a method?  I'm not sure overriding a method "on the fly" is what you are wanting to do.

Comment: @Blorgbeard, would that require me create a new class for each of the different stored procedures?

Comment: No, one class, just pass a different delegate for each sproc.

Comment: @MarshallTigerus, this is in a very big project, shared with multiple developers. Changing the method signature requires management involvement for approval and weeks of downtime to get this approved.

Comment: Basically, what @Evk wrote in his answer below.

Comment: @jp2code I feel your pain, but anything you're going to do is going to require a change to the class and interface.

Comment: @MarshallTigerus not true - Evk's answer only involves a new subclass, no change to original interface or class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you can just do

```
class DynamicTest : Test {
    private readonly Action _getData;
    public DynamicTest(Action getData) {
        _getData = getData;
    }
    public override void GetData() {
        _getData();
    }
}
```

And then

```
var test = new DynamicTest(() => {
      Console.WriteLine("Dynamic");
});
```

Comment: I won for 2 seconds! XD

Comment: @Gusman true :) Though our answers are a bit different so I'll leave mine still.

Comment: {GASP!} That worked! ...well, it doesn't have any red squiggly lines under it, at least. Let me test it....

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you just want to be able to assign some external function, then redefine your interface, instead of a function use an Action:

```
internal interface ITest
{
    Action GetData{ get; set; }
}

internal class Test : ITest
{
    public Action GetData  { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can do what you wanted:

```
var t = new Test();
t.GetData = () =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Anonymous - Hello World!");
};
```

And you can call it as

```
t.GetData();
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass the name of the stored procedure to execute to the method `Test`.

Simplicity is the king.

```
internal interface ITest
{
    virtual void GetData(string spname);
}

internal class Test : ITest
{
    public void GetData(string spname)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Executing store proc: " + spname);
    }
}
```

Comment: One assumes the interface can't change.